# Problems displaying the price

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, laravel-9

I'm having a problem printing the price.
Specifically, since I am on an information update page, when the page is reloaded it initially prints me the total cost (therefore the sum) of the selected treatment prices. So far, so good.

Then I have two inputs where I calculate the discount (the calculation to calculate the discount is not shown in the code (I'll do it later) because I'm having problems, explained below, and I need to solve these problems first otherwise the calculation will be incorrect).

In the inputs, I first select whether it is the relative discount or the absolute discount input.

If it is the *first case*, I want to add to the price already present (therefore the one obtained from the sum of the treatments selected from the checkbox) the value that I am going to insert in this input and calculate it every time a numeric key is pressed. I am realizing that when I add a number, if for example I have 7 as the starting number, if I put 11 in the input, the sum is not 18 but **19** (this is because it first adds the sum of the first 1 (therefore 7 + 1 = 8) is subsequently 8 + 11 (so 19)), while I want to get 18. How can I solve this problem?

In the *second case*, if I put a number on the second input, obviously leaving the first blank (so no value is put in the first) I get **NaN**.
I need to fix these problems.

Can anyone kindly help me?

**HTML**

```
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <div for="treatment" class="form-label">List treatments</div>
                        @foreach ($treatments as $treatment)
                            <input class="checkp" type="checkbox" id="{{$treatment->title}}" data-price="{{$treatment->price}}" name="treatments[]" value="{{$treatment->id}}" @if (count($quote->treatments->where('id', $treatment->id))) checked @endif>
                            <label for="{{$treatment->title}}"> {{$treatment->title}} - </label><span class="price"> {{$treatment->price}}</span><br>
                        @endforeach
                    <p class="mt-5">Total price: <span id="total-price"></span></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="discount" class="form-label">Discount</label>
                    <div class="form-check my-2 mb-3">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="discount" id="flexRadioNoDisconunt" value="nodiscount" checked>
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioNoDisconunt"> No discount </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check my-2 mb-3">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="discount" id="flexRadioRelativeDisconunt" value="relativediscount">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioRelativeDisconunt"> Relative discount (in %)</label>
                        <input type="number" id="inputrelativediscount" class="form-control p-3 inputs selectorelative" min="0" max="100" name="relativediscount" value="{{$quote->relativediscount }}">                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check my-2 mb-3">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="discount" id="flexRadioAbsoluteDisconunt" value="absolutediscount">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioAbsoluteDisconunt"> Absolute discount (in €)</label>
                        <input type="number" id="inputabsolutediscount" class="form-control p-3 inputs selectorabsolute" min="0" name="absolutediscount" value="{{ $quote->absolutediscount }}">
                    </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').forEach((elem) => elem.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        if (event.target.checked) {
            sum = sum + parseInt(elem.getAttribute('data-price'))
        } else {
            let el = parseInt(elem.getAttribute('data-price'))
            sum = sum - el
        }
        //console.log(sum); 
        document.getElementById("total-price").innerHTML = sum;
    }));

    document.querySelectorAll('.inputs').forEach((elem) => elem.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
        if (document.querySelector('.selectorelative')) {
            document.getElementById("total-price").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("total-price").innerHTML) + parseInt(document.querySelector('.selectorelative').value);            
        } else {
            document.getElementById("total-price").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("total-price").innerHTML) + parseInt(document.querySelector('.selectorabsolute').value); 
        }

    }
    ))
```

Comment: You have to store the original price in secondary location, so you can reuse the original price every time you make a new calculation.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware but I do it with the sum variable. Or am I wrong? Could you kindly help me do this?

Comment: The sum variable is only present in the "click" code for checkboxes, the updating of the price is done in the "keyup" code for inputs. In the latter you overwrite the original prices. Normally you would store the original price in [an data attribute of the input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) and reuse that on every calculation.

Comment: ok can you kindly show me with an answer?

Comment: @Sarah: putting a little more effort on posting a **working** snippet will increase your chances for a nice answer...

Comment: What Louys is referring to is a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).